# Is the python ipdb package available inside another package?

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

I can't install the ipdb package because it's on a server over which I have no control. I want to make the following work.

```
import other.module.ipdb as ipdb

print 'hello'
ipdb.set_trace()
print 'world'
```

Ipython is installed which makes me think I should somehow be able to access the ipdb package. I know locally I did installed it by doing `sudo apt-get install python-ipdb` but it seems that ipdb should already be available somehow.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Just copy ipdb into your own project? https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/blob/master/ipdb/__main__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that IPython comes with everything you need to be able to use the `ipdb` package. Here's how you can access it as long as you have IPython installed:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
ipdb = Pdb()
```

Then you can use `ipdb` just as though you had done `import ipdb`, such as:

```
ipdb.runcall(self, func, *args, **kwds)
ipdb.run(self, cmd, globals=None, locals=None)
# etc.
```